# How Amazon ELB Health check Works?

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, healthcheck

I am having problems configuring ELB for my servers.

I start 2 micro instances with the exact same conf and try to do Load Balancing. However they never pass the health check (HTTP port 80 path:"/").

- Ping is ok on the website. So is telnet on 80.

How did the health check works? Am I doing anything really wrong?

EDIT:

- Both Direct browser access and GET (via curl) works correctly (status 200)

Comment: I have the same problem. I just have it checking TCP:80 as an interim solution (which works fine).

Comment: It worked! Thanks! But I still dont know how the health check works .. :(
Can you write an answer so I can check it as accepted?

Comment: Are you using Django? Are you redirect HTTP to HTTPS? I summarized my experience how to solve AWS ELB health check with HTTP to my blog: http://androidkr.blogspot.kr/2014/03/aws-elb-health-check-for-django.html

Comment: They both don't pass the health check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. I just have it checking TCP:80 as an interim solution (which works fine).

Answer (score 2):

I've come to the conclusion that the response, apart from being a HTTP 200 response, must contain certain headers. I've had a HTTP 200 returned from my tomcat server running on the instance not work, but a static html page served by httpd (also returning a 200 code) work fine. Looking at the headers, one of the few differences was that the tomcat one didn't contain the content-type. Not sure why that would make a difference, though.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it performs an HTTP GET request to the specified path "/", of each of the servers and looks for a successful HTTP response code (200). Can you successfully make a GET request to `http://<backend_server_IP>:80/` via a browser (or CLI tool such as `wget` or `curl`).

If the request is served successfully, the second thing to ask is: have you configured your servers' security group so that access to port 80 is limited to a particular source address or subnet? If so, you need to add ELB's security group to the filter. The group is always called:

```
amazon-elb/amazon-elb-sg
```

So you can just add this under the 'Source' field in the Security Groups section of the AWS Console.

Comment: The port 80 is open to the world (0.0.0.0/0). Both direct browser access and curl works correctly (200)

Comment: Are the webservers bound only to the public IP/domain? I assume ELB uses the internal (private) IPs so that no external bandwidth is used. Can you successfully make a request from one of your Amazon instances to http://<private_IP>:80/  
If so then I'm out of ideas!

Comment: It was not accessible working with the internal IP. I changed it, its now working, but the health check still not passing.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using a specific domain name on your web server.
Or you set up your web server to meet any request (binding *) or follow [the documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html).

Answer (score 0):

so i've just got the http check to work by pointing it at a static html file (as opposed to a php page).

'/' does not work despite it returning a valid http status when using curl, etc.
'/file.html' does however pass the health check.

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, Ensure the ELB security traffic has allowed traffic back
  from the instance, and the instance security group allows traffic
  from the ELB.
- It was mentioned response must be 200
- And finally do    you have more than one interface from what I can
  tell it will choose    randomly which interface.
- ELB Needs to be in a subnet with internet route to IGW